# How to redirect after Header has been sent node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following in my admin.js controller file

```
module.exports = {
  getAdmin: async (req, res) => {

 let ref = req.headers.referer;

if ((ref === undefined) || (!ref.includes('user'))) {
  res.writeHead(301,
  {Location: '/'}
);
res.end();

 res.render('admin', { indexCSS: true })
 }

  }
```

What I would like to do, is that if the User comes from `/user` he can visit the `/admin` page otherwise he is redirected to `/` i.e. `home` but. It works if the user comes from a valid referrer, but when I try to go to the route directly it redirects correctly but the app crashes and I get the error `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Is there a way that I can redirect without getting that error.

What have I done wrong in my approach

Thanks in advance

**Please be aware that this does not include authentication**

Answer (score 0):

`res.end()` doesn't work like return of a function. You get that error because after using writeHead `res.end()` is called which sends back response and then the code tries to render 'admin'

```js
module.exports = {
        getAdmin: async (req, res) => {

            let ref = req.headers.referer;

            if ((ref === undefined) || (!ref.includes('user'))) {
                res.writeHead(301, {
                    Location: '/'
                });
            } else {
                res.render('admin', {
                    indexCSS: true
                })
            }
            res.end()
       }
```